# Copy a folder with files and folders

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a subdir and in there, there are many more folders and files. So what I want is to copy the **subdir** with all the folders and files.

This is what it looks like now:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
└── src
    ├── a
    └── subdir
        └── b
        └──subdir2
           └── c
        └──subdir3
           └── d
           └──subdir4
              └── e
```

This is how I want it to look after using Grunt:

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
└── src
    ├── a
    └── subdir
        └── b
        └──subdir2
           └── c
        └──subdir3
           └── d
           └──subdir4
              └── e
└── dist
    └── subdir
        └── b
        └──subdir2
           └── c
        └──subdir3
           └── d
           └──subdir4
              └── e
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it just isn't working. It copies everything also `src` folder and file `a`:

```
copy: {
        expand: true,
        src: 'src/subdir/*',
        dest: 'dist/'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'src/',
  src: 'subdir/**',
  dest: 'dist/'
},
```

The **cwd** option is here for that